# '500' error with sails.js 'testProject'

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

Went to http://sailsjs.org/#!getStarted and went through the steps the page requires.  In my Win7 environment, I have node running and tested.  I installed sails.js, changed directories, and 'sails lift'.  Sails.js succeeds in launching and the CLI looks like:

```
$ sails lift
info:
info:
info:    Sails.js           <|
info:    v0.9.7              |\
info:                       /|.\
info:                      / || \
info:                    ,'  |'  \
info:                 .-'.-==|/_--'
info:                 `--'-------'
info:    __---___--___---___--___---___--___
info:  ____---___--___---___--___---___--___-__
info:
info: Server lifted in `c:\Users\Dad\My Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\First Sails Project\t
estProject`
info: To see your app, visit http://localhost:1337
info: To shut down Sails, press <CTRL> + C at any time.

debug: --------------------------------------------------------
debug: :: Wed Nov 06 2013 14:06:25 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
debug:
debug: Environment      : development
debug: Port             : 1337
debug: --------------------------------------------------------
```

But when I visit the port I get this on the page:

```
{
  "status": 500,
  "errors": [
    "Failed to lookup view \"home/index\""
  ]
}
```

There is a very long trace at the CLI that begins:

```
error: Error rendering view at :: c:\Users\Dad\My Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\First Sails
 Project\testProject/views/home/index
error: Using layout located at :: c:\Users\Dad\My Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\First Sails
 Project\testProject/views/layout
error: Server Error (500)
error: Error: Failed to lookup view "home/index"
    at Function.app.render (c:\Users\Dad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\expr
ess\lib\application.js:495:17)
.
.
.
```

The global install of sails.js went fine.  All files are present in the views directory.  I'm running node v0.8.18 and other apps I have run/render fine.  Looking at the '500.js' file in the 'config' directory, if the 'view doesn't exist, just send json' (which is what seems to be happening).  But the view does appear to exist so ... what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a known [issue](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/983) on windows. check the work around in the linked issue or use sails 0.9.4 till the next release.